# Does anyone know a simpler way to solve this increment a vector of numbers?

Tags: matlab

Problem statement:

Take as input an array of digits (e.g. `x = [1 2 3]`) and output an array of digits that is that number "incremented" properly, (in this case, `y = [1 2 4]`).

Examples of proper input/output:

```
x = [1 9 1 9] ----> y = [1 9 2 0]
```

and

```
x = [9 9 9] ----> y = [1 0 0 0]
```

I thought the easiest solution would be to convert the vector to a matrix, increment it, and then convert back. It sounds convoluted but it worked better than trying to do the addition normally.

My attempt:

```
function ans = incrementor(x)
x=sprintf('%1d',x)
x=str2num(x)
num2str(x+1) - '0'
```

Can anyone come up with a more efficient solution?

(I'm thinking there may be a command to perform the addition directly without converting to a scalar, but I don't know it.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that matlab has no native function for what you need, at some point you will have to convert your values ​​in scalar mode to increase

Comment: Nope. See for example my answer

Answer (score 0):

Combine the digits, add 1,

```
yn=x*(10.^(length(x)-1:-1:0))' + 1
```

Then convert back:

```
numDigits = floor(log10(yn)+1)
tens = 10.^(1:numDigits);
y = fliplr(floor(mod(yn,tens)./(tens/10)))
```

Or, as the OP (user3020151) points out, you can convert back with `num2str`:

```
y = num2str(yn) - '0'
```

Addressing the search for a single command, I do not know of a built-in command, but you can construct an anonymous function as follows:

```
>> incrementor = @(x) num2str(x*(10.^(length(x)-1:-1:0)).' + 1) - '0'; %' anonymous
>> x = [9 9 9];
>> y = incrementor(x)
y =
     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: That gets the job done but it is longer than mine. It could be improved by replacing the last three lines with " y=num2str(x) - '0' "

Comment: @user3020151 Yes that is true, I just wanted to show the pure numeric solution. I didn't realize you were going for fewer line.  In terms of efficiency, I'd argue that not converting to and from strings is better, or perhaps it is just feels better.  ;) Anyway, I don't know of a single command that will perform this operation.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your effort.

Comment: @user3020151 It's not a built-in, but you could try the anonymous  function I just added.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use strings or convert to a number: Just find the rightmost non-nine digit (if any), add 1 to it, and set any digit to its right to zero. The case when all digits are nine needs to be dealt with separately, because then the numer of digits has to be increased.

```
k = find(x~=9,1,'last');
if isempty(k)
  y = [1 zeros(1,numel(x))];
else
  y = [x(1:k-1) x(k)+1 zeros(1,numel(x)-k)];
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [1 2 3];
r1=sprintf('%1d',x);
r1= str2num(r1) + 1;
r2=sscanf( sprintf( num2str(r1) ), '%1d' )'
```

Comment: This is basically the same as my solution except your last line is less efficient.